# setup $http url from .properties file in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some services in my App.

```
loginApp.factory('urlService', function() {
return {
    baseUrl : function(){
        return 'http://localhost:8080/myAppName'
        }
    }
});
```

consume this service by one another services.

```
loginApp.factory('loginServices', function($http,urlService) {
    return {
        loginAuth : function(aut,resp){
            return $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: urlService.baseUrl()+'auth', 
            }).success(function(result) {
                   return result;
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I want configure **`http://localhost:8080/myAppName`** from a .properties file which is present on application root.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like this

```
angular.module('app.properties', []).provider('properties', function() {

    var resource;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'properties.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        success: function(data) {
            resource  = data;
        }
    });
    this.properties= resource;
    this.$get = function() {
        return this.properties;
    };
});
```

Then use this provider in you controller/services to access the properties

```
 angular.module('loginApp', ['app.properties']).factory('urlService', function(properties) {
return {
    baseUrl : function(){
        return properties.baseUrl;
        }
    }
});
```

And your properties.json should be like

```
{
"baseUrl" :"http://localhost:8080/myAppName"
}
```

NB : I have used jquery ajax to load the properties.json because it should not be an async call, so I set async: false

```
  $.ajax({
            url: 'properties.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            **async: false**,
            success: function(data) {
                resource  = data;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best option in that case would be to create a service that then can be injected and in that service pull the config file and assign content to a returned variable (hope it makes sense so far)

Although that will leave you with possible race issues when i.e. your `loginService` will be called before config was loaded but if you make a good use of promises all this will be trivial for you